# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. #Flutter, #Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, mobile, build.gradle, development-environment

Recently I faced the problem with this error in Flutter App development Android Studio, Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

Solution:
1 open project level build.gradle then replace your ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32' with new version according to release so I replaced ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32' with this ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0' and solved.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually caused by the outdated Kotlin gradle plugin version configured in the Flutter project's Android build. To solve this issue, update the plugin version located at the project-level build.gradle located in `{FLUTTER_PROJECT}/android/build.gradle`